# Pandas grouping two columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have the following dataframe:

| Date | ID | Brand | Product |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-01-2023 | 123 | Apple | Macbook |
| 01-01-2023 | 123 | Microsoft | Surface |
| 01-01-2023 | 839 | Oneplus | 9T |
| 02-01-2023 | 123 | Samsung | S10 |
| 02-01-2023 | 942 | LG | V10 |
| 02-01-2023 | 942 | Samsung | S23 |

The desired output I'm struggling to make is this:
[image]
So in essence, grouping my results per date and not have it repeat the same date. Do the same for the same ID within the same date. In the end I need a pandas dataframe to push it into an excel. Can someone help me in the right direction?

I have tried to use GroupBy but it forces be to calculate something since a groupby object doesn't contain anything. I'm not calculating anything here, just grouping. Then I tried setting index with two columns but it kept repeating the date and ID, I need them to be format in the picture above.

I tried experimenting with MultiIndex but couldn't find my way through. I wasn't sure how to go from dataframe to arrays that MultiIndex was asking.
Any ideas?

Comment: From your question description, multi-index is indeed the way to go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
df.set_index(['Date', 'ID', 'Brand']).to_excel('A.xlsx')
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df_marks = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['Somu', 'Kiku', 'Amol', 
'Lini'],'physics':[68, 74, 77, 78],'chemistry': [84, 56, 73, 
69],'algebra': [78, 88, 82, 87]})
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx')
df_marks.to_excel(writer, 'marks')
writer.save()
```

Try this as it is the basic one, it may help